# python decorators and wrappers

Tags: python, function, class, decorator

I am having a hard time grasping decorators, I initially thought decorators were syntactic sugar to do an operation such as:

```
def decorator(x):
    return x*2

@decorator
def plusone(x):
    return x+1

print plusone(5)
# would print twelve, because: decorator(plusone(5)) as I have seen 
# in some tutorials
```

but I've noticed that a wrapper function needs to be created in the decorator first.

Why do we need to return a function, not an integer?

Comment: Because that's what decorators do: they take a function and return a new function.  Have you read [the documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) and/or googled for any of the zillion explanations of Python decorators out there?

Comment: Your decorator essentially makes it a new function (that takes the same arguments). The decorator itself does not *call* (evaluate) your function though, because it doesn't know the arguments. Iif you want to return `x() * 2` inside the decorator, what would be the argument to `x()`?

Comment: @brenbarn yes I have, that's why I came here as a last resort. hoping one of you could explain it a little clearer.

Comment: @vjgaero: Then perhaps you should explain why you think decorators behave as you suggest in this question.  What did you read that gave you that impression?

Comment: @brenBarn because of the decorator tutorials I have read. some tutors have explained that decorators are "pretty much" what ive explained above.

Answer (score 3):

A (Python) decorator is syntactic sugar for a function modifying a function, causing the latter function to act like a modified version of itself.

Let's start with a simple (and not so good) example. Say we write

```
def double_me(f):
    return lambda x: 2 * f(x)
```

which takes a function taking one parameter, and returns a function taking one parameter and returning double what the original function would return. Then we can use it like this:

```
def double_the_add_one(x):
    return x + 1
double_the_add_one = double_me(double_the_add_one)

>>> double_the_add_one(1)
4
```

Note that we first defined `double_the_add_one`, then modified `double_the_add_one` and bound it back to `double_the_add_one`. So now it is just a modified version of itself - it does what it would do originally, then just doubles the result. Decorators simply make this a bit more succinct:

```
@double_me 
def double_the_add_one(x):
    return x + 1

>>> double_the_add_one(1)
4
```

---

Note that the above decorator wasn't that great:

1. It assumed there was a single positional argument.
2. It assumed there were no keyword arguments.
3. If the decorated function had a docstring, it was clobbered.

You should probably use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) to actually write decorators using the example in the docs there.