# What's going to happen in the python decorator that defines one more function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Today, when I was studying decorators, I had a question，Look at the following two pieces of code
code 1：

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        print('call %s():' % func.__name__)
        return func(*args,**kw)
return wrapper

@log
def now():
    print('2018-8-28')

now()
```

code 2：

```
def log(func):
    print('call %s():' % func.__name__)
    return func

@log
def now():
    print('2018-8-28')

now()
print(type(now()))
```

Why does the first code define more than one wrapper function? The output of both codes is the same.

In code 2, I used the `type` method for the now function to see it's type, and the result type is `None`.

Comment: It is more useful to post excerpts of code as text in your question, rather than links to screenshots.

Comment: The first one defines one decorator and one wrapper. The second defines no wrapper at all. The output is only the same because you do nothing in-between. Run them twice and you should see a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python decorators and wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614331/python-decorators-and-wrappers)

Comment: Thanks to the respondents above, and I'll take a closer look at your responses, there shouldn't be many questions

Answer (score 2):

Using `@log` (or some other decorator) before the function definition will *call* the decorator function (`log` in this case) with the decorated function as the argument, and replace the decorated function with the function returned by the decorator function, i.e. it is similar to doing `now = log(now)` after the initial declaration of the function.

Thus the "short" version will print the "call" line once when the function is decorated and then returns the function itself. The "long" version on the other hand prints the "call" line each time the function is called by returning a new function wrapping the original function and doing the logging.

Your output is the same, as you call the function just once right after decorating it.

Answer (score 0):

***Why does the first figure define more than one wrapper function?***

A **decorator** is passed the function it's decorating; which is then encapsulated inside the `wrapper` function, hence the naming.

*Image 1* is no different from doing what's in image 2 though (if you don't need to use a wrapping function):

```
def log(func):
    return func('hello there')

@log
def now(msg):
    print(msg)
```

In the example given there's no specific need to use a `wrapper`, although there are cases that require using a `wrapper` function. - Note: you're implicitly replacing one function with another when you wrap a function.